# El uso de "ya" en frases como "ya me voy" y "ya termino"

Tags: uso-de-palabras, tiempos-verbales

Como ya se sabe, la palabra "ya", aunque muy pequeña, es un concepto bastante difícil para los que no son hablantes nativos de español. El uso de "ya" en el tiempo presente y afirmativo a mí me ha confundido un poco, y desde eso viene la pregunta:

"Ya" se puede usar como "ahora mismo." Por ejemplo: "Ya estoy de vacaciones, pero mañana volvemos a la escuela"

"Ya" se puede usar también con el pasado para enfatizar un cambio: "Cuando era niño comía mucha carne pero ya soy vegetariano."

Lo que me confunde es el uso de "ya" cuando se dice "Ya me voy", "Ya termino", "Ya vuelvo", o "Ya regreso".

Aquí "ya" significa que pronto va a pasar lo que dije. Cuando escucho esas frases distintas, entiendo que "ya" tiene este significado pero la pregunta es:

**¿Se puede usar "ya" para significar que muy pronto algo va a suceder con verbos que no son "ir(se)", "terminar", "volver", o "regresar"?**

Comment: https://dle.rae.es/ya?m=form es de interes.

Comment: In the mentioned contexts "ya" means "right away".

Comment: @Gustavson not quite though because in english I would say "I'll be back soon", or "I'm almost done". Only in the case of ir(se) does it translate to "I'm leaving right away." But they are all the same concept.

Comment: I meant to say, in the future (and in the present with future meaning), "ya" conveys the sense of immediacy.

Comment: @Gustavson oh that makes sense. ¿Así que lo que quieres decir es que esos verbos con conjugaciones en el presente, aunque se conjugan así, hablan del futuro? Semejante a algo como "Mañana tengo una cita con el médico." (Aquí tengo es conjugado en el presente pero habla del futuro.) ¿Y la importancia del "ya" en mis ejemplos (porque hablan del futuro) es que solo le dan un sentido de inmediatez?

Comment: Exactly! If you think it's worth it, I can make a reply along those lines.

Comment: En lugar de "Ya estoy en vacaciones", en España solemos usar "Ya estoy de vacaciones"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supongo que la dificultad viene del hecho de que en los últimos ejemplos, aunque sólo se usa la palabra 'ya', en realidad se está usando una 'abreviatura' y, por tanto, omitiendo parte de la expresión (que cualquier nativo entiende subliminalmente sin necesidad de que aparezca).

Por ejemplo:
En las expresiones "Ya me voy", "Ya termino", "Ya vuelvo", o "Ya regreso". En realidad se está diciendo "**Ya mismo** me voy", "**Ya mismo** termino", "**Ya mismo** vuelvo" o "**Ya mismo** regreso". Que también se puede traducir por 'Enseguida' o 'Ahora mismo': "En seguida me voy", "Ahora mismo termino", "Enseguida vuelvo" y "Ahora mismo regreso".

Aunque en estos ejemplos, "Ya" se está usando como ahora mismo, en el primer ejemplo, **no significa eso**. En este caso, "Ya" sólo se usa justo en el momento en el que ha empezado la acción: *"Ya estoy de vacaciones, pero mañana volvemos a la escuela"* se suele usar únicamente justo al empezar las vacaciones. Si, por ejemplo, llevo ya varios días de vacaciones, no solemos usar esa expresión. Para entenderlo, una expresión equivalente sería: *"Por fin estoy de vacaciones" o "Al fin estoy de vacaciones"*. Es decir, enfatizando el comienzo del nuevo estado como algo que esperábamos con muchas ganas. Otros ejemplos serían: "Ya hemos llegado", "Ya estoy aquí", "Ya he terminado la tarea".

En cuánto al segundo ejemplo, aunque está correctamente construido, "suena raro" en español. Es más usual decir *"Cuando era niño comía mucha carne pero ahora soy vegetariano."* y, como ejemplos de un cambio en el pasado, tendríamos frases como: *"Cuando era niño comía mucha carne pero ya no."*, *"¿Has hecho tus deberes? Sí, ya los terminé.*, *"Ya no fumo"*, *"Ya no suelo montar en bici"*, *"Ya no te quiero"*, *"*Ya te lo dije*"*.

Finalmente, y respondiendo a la pregunta, puedes usar 'ya' con cualquier verbo para sustituir 'Ahora mismo' o 'Enseguida': *"Ya le escribo"*, *"Ya subo"*, *"Ya lo hago"*, *"Ya me pongo los zapatos"*, *"Ya recojo mi habitación"*, *"Ya me monto en el coche"*, *"Ya lo limpio"*, *"Ya le ayudo"*. En estos ejemplos, el contexto más claro es cuándo alguien te pide que hagas algo y usas esas expresiones como respuesta:

- ¿Puedes escribirle a tu amigo Juan? Ya le escribo.
- ¿Puedes subir un momento a tu habitación? Ya subo.
- ¿Puedes ayudarle a tu hermano? Ya le ayudo.

Y, si alguien dice: "¿Puede alguien abrir la puerta?" la respuesta más común es: "Ya lo hago yo" o "Ya la abro yo" o "Ya abro yo la puerta".

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. Ahora tiene mucho más sentido.

Answer (score 1):

I think "Ya" is most closely related to "Now" in English, using your examples:

Ya estoy en vacaciones...
Now I am on vacation

in the last examples like in "Ya me voy" the word Ya is used like Now as a means to convey urgency. As you would say in English "I am leaving right now", meaning I haven't left yet but you need to get that I'm about to.

Answering your question, I'd say yes, you can say things like
Ya esta reparado el auto (the car is now repaired)
Ya se rompió la tele (the tv is now broken)